# Why is my channel undefined?

Tags: discord, discord.io

I'm working on a Discord bot that will take complaints via DMs and post them in a chat room to be seen by moderators.  For some reason, the type is considered undefined.  The exact error text is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '44640...' of undefined
```

The error comes from this line:

```
if (bot.channel[channelID].type == 1)
```

If the channel ID itself is considered undefined, then I believe this means the channel itself is not defined.

Here is the full code of the function:

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
// Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
// It will listen for messages that will start with `s!`
if (message.substring(0, 2) == 's!') {
    var args = message.substring(2).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(2);
    switch(cmd) {
        // s!ping
        case 'ping':
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: 'Pong!'
            });
        break;

        case 'problem':
        if (bot.channel[channelID].type == 1) 
        {
            var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
            .setDescription(message.content)
            .setTimestamp(new Date())
            .setColor('#C735D4');
            //stores the sent message, along with the sender and the time of the message

            client.channels.get(446393832066514947).send(embed);
            //sends message to channel
        }
        // Just add any case commands if you want to..
     }
 }
});
```

Comment: I believe you're trying to use 2 different libraries. `bot.sendMessage()` is not Discord.JS, but the way you generating that Rich Embed looks like Discord.JS. What library are you actually using?

Comment: @AndréPaulo I'm using Discord.io

Answer (score 0):

If that is your entire code, I am assuming `this.channel` is never set anywhere, which means it will be `undefined` when you try to access it.

Your `Client` object holds a collection of `Channel` objects, with the channel ID as the key.

So in your snippet you should be able to say

```
bot.channels[channelID].type
```

Comment: if (bot.channel[channelID].type == 1)  produces an error in which the ChannelID is an undefined property.

Comment: @MarkGradl  `bot.channels` holds a collection of channels, not `bot.channel`